# Seam 2.2.2.Final Messages to display after a4j:mediaOutput

Tags: jsf, seam2

i have an xhtml like this:

```
<a4j:outputPanel id="displayGraph" layout="block" style="clear:both; margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 80px;margin-bottom: 20px;">
        <a4j:mediaOutput element="img"  cacheable="false" session="false" createContent="#{generateGraph.paint}" value="#{graph}" mimeType="image/png" standby="Loading" /> 
    </a4j:outputPanel>

    <a4j:outputPanel id="errorMessage" ajaxRendered="true">
        <h:messages id="messages" styleClass="message" errorClass="errormsg" infoClass="infomsg" warnClass="warnmsg"/>
    </a4j:outputPanel>
```

also i have paint method in backing bean which generates message if the method gives exception. like this:

```
public void paint(OutputStream os, Object data) {
    try{ 
           //some actions
  } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      FacesMessages.instance().add(Severity.ERROR, "Sorry connection can not be achieved");
  }

} else {
      FacesMessages.instance().add(Severity.ERROR, "Sorry server does not exist");

}

}
```

now the messages are never shown. could anyone kindly tell me what i am doing wrong?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

FacesMessages is a conversation-scoped seam component. Supposing you are using temporary conversations, this is what happens:

1. Initial request to JSF page. Temporary conversation #1 created.
2. JSF page rendered, conversation #1 killed.
3. AJAX request for mediaOutput. Temporary conversaton #2 created.
4. Image is rendered. FacesMessages object bound to conversation #2.
5. Image is returned. Conversation #2 killed.
6. a4j:outputPanel is ajaxRendered. Temporary conversation #3 created.
7. An empty FacesMessages is rendered in conversation #3.

You can test this by including `#{conversation.id}` in both your a4j:outputPanels, and by logging the Conversation ID in your `paint()` method.

There are two solutions to this problem. Either you start a long-running conversation, and add  to your mediaOutput. The other solution is to not use FacesMessages but a custom PAGE-scoped component to keep your messages.

You can also switch to RichFaces4, which includes a "render" argument for every richfaces component, which makes sure the rerender is issued in the same request as the initial mediaOutput AJAX request.